# In ELK, how can I search for a log that does not match another?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

Let's say I have logs before and after an operation, like below:

[XXXX] Operation A started
[XXXX] Operation A completed

Assuming that XXXX is unique for each execution, now I want to find out the execution that has been started, but not completed yet. Which means that I need to find out XXXX that have the "started" log, but no "completed" log. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not answering your question but I would look into https://www.elastic.co/blog/alerting-on-machine-learning-jobs-in-elasticsearch-v55

Comment: Also if you are talking just about simple casy like started and stopped actions then you can use aggregations and search where only 1 item is in bucket

Comment: I tried your way with bucket_selector to get those only with 1 item. It works using Query DSL, but sadly I wanna use it with Grafana, which does not support it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [elapsed filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elapsed.html) to match up the start/end events.  The filter allows you to define a period in which you would expect the end event, and, if one is not received, it will create an expired event.

Comment: Looks like exactly what I want! Let me try this out. Thanks!

Comment: The plugin can only add fields to the end event. It doesn't help finding the start events which are still in progress (and not expired).

Comment: Completed events will be shown in the end event.  Events that time out will have their own end events.  Events that are still running will not have an end event.  I can't find the code right now, but I've built a system using these three states before.  IIRC, I would run the two queries (start, end) and correlate the two results to find the running events.  Hope that helps.